# How to build a account validation system with flask and mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm learning Flask by reading the book http://flaskbook.com/# (some of the code I posted below is been taken from the examples in the book) but I want to use mongodb as database so I use the flask-mongoengine extension. Actually I'm trying to build an account validation system and you can find below my source code:

```
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from flask.ext.login import UserMixin

app = Flask(__name__)
db = MongoEngine(app)

class User(UserMixin, db.Document):
    email = db.StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    username = db.StringField(required=True, unique=True, max_length=50)
    password_hash = db.StringField(max_length=128)

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('Password is not a readable attribute!')

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
```

and below you can see my problem in the shell:

```
>>> from my_app import User
>>> u = User(email='example@mail.com', username='bestuser', password='ciao')
>>> u.password_hash
>>> "no output here"
```

but if I do like that:

```
>>> u.password = 'ciao'
>>> u.password_hash
'pbkdf2:sha1:1000$39qJ6zDT$4f2a446acc7205ad53f0b5cc5409b2d9420c29a5'
```

It works properly.

So I don't actually know how to fix this problem. Every suggestion is very welcome.
Thank you in advance and if you need more information just ask.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely have to create an explicit `__init__` method -- similar to SQLAlchemy.

```
def __init__(self, email, username, password):
    self.email = email
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
```

Then you should get the correct behavior.

Comment: thank you very much for you answer but if I do like you said I get another error: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute '_data'